# How do I make blender operate in Left Hand

Tags: model, 3d, directx, export, blender

so I'm having a small problem with blender.

The coordinate plan seems to be messed up (y is forward, z is up). I've done some research, and apparently this is a "right-hand" system, and you can change it in the export by making  z up and y forward, but my problem is, the x is still reversed, and I need to flip it (x = x * 1.0). Also, the UV map is strange, I need to flip the V coordinate (v = 1.0 - v). Is there any way to make blender operate in a "left-hand" system. It's a bit of a pain, because I'm exporting the objects to use in D3D.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you've solved your problem already a long time ago, but my answer might help others. I've met the identical problem. Symptoms were (in addition to yours) wrong UV coordinates of test cube rendered. The reason is, Blender exports data in the Right-Hand Coordinate System. Changing Blender settings when exporting Wavefront won't help. The solution is to invert Z, Normal-Z and Texture-V, and also revert the vertex drawing order, by changing index array or vertex order in vertex array, depends on you.

```cpp
// Invert every Z coord of v entry:
z = -1.0f * input.z;

// Invert every Z coord of vn entry:
nz = -1.0f * input.nz;

// Invert every V coord of vt entry:
tv = 1.0f - input.tv;

...
// When assembling vertices:
// Revert face order from 0->1->2 to 2->1->0, depending on your implementation.
```

Comment: Just what I needed, as a side note, to reverse the face order you can just swap the last two vertices of each triplet

Comment: It should be noted for anyone who sees this in the future, that the exporter for blender inverts the V coordinate of your texture coordinates. I was able to prove this by dynamically generating a mesh at runtime, sampling from a tileset rectangle, which had an inverted texture upon render. I had previously flipped my textures to make them work with the obj format. Turns out the textures themselves were not loaded upside down as many people erroneously state. The obj format itself, for whatever reason, is inverted. Use 1-v to counter this in your loader.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that DirectX uses a left-handed coordinate system.

This [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204853%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) includes a description of what you need to do to import data from a right-handed system (I'm assuming that Blender is right-handed because of your question). These are the main points

> Direct3D uses a left-handed coordinate system. If you are porting an application that is based on a right-handed coordinate system, you must make two changes to the data passed to Direct3D.
>
> - Flip the order of triangle vertices so that the system traverses them clockwise from the front. In other words, if the vertices are v0, v1, v2, pass them to Direct3D as v0, v2, v1.
> - Use the view matrix to scale world space by -1 in the z-direction. To do this, flip the sign of the _31, _32, _33, and _34 member of the D3DMATRIX structure that you use for your view matrix.

It's possibly going to be easier to leave Blender as it is and make the above changes on import to D3D.

Answer (score 0):

you can switch between it by fliping x and z and when converting between quats and euler use the following:

```
vec quat2euler()
{
    float W = this->w;
    float X = this->x;
    float Z = -this->z;
    float Y = this->y;
    float WSquared = W * W;
    float XSquared = X * X;
    float YSquared = Y * Y;
    float ZSquared = Z * Z;
    float yaw = (-2.0f * ((X * Z) - (Y * W)));
    vec TEuler(0);
    TEuler.x = (atan2f(2.0f * (Y * Z + X * W), -XSquared - YSquared + ZSquared + WSquared));
    TEuler.y = (asin(yaw >= 1.0f ? 1.00f : yaw <= -1.0f ? -1.00f : yaw));
    TEuler.z = (atan2f(2.0f * (X * Y + Z * W), XSquared - YSquared - ZSquared + WSquared));
    TEuler.mul(180.0f / PI);//90,180,270
    return TEuler;
}
```

There is a minor error where is can go outside of the bounds of -1 to 1 this function test this as well.

The fromula is orginally from:
 http://www.irrlicht3d.org/wiki/index.php?n=Main.GettingStartedWithBullet

At least this is how i sovled it, its a zup left hand system.